# Is it possible to have a multi channel conversation on Slack?

Tags: slack

We have a Slack with hundreds of people. Sometime I need to get two different teams on a short conversation together.

Is creating a new channel the only way to get everyone together? This seems weird.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this hack today, for this question I had for a while (but didn't find on SO, so I posted it).

**Create a picture (1px white) and post it to the channel of your team/product #1. Then go on your files (three dot menu), select the image and share in to the channel of your product/team #2.
All the comment posted on the picture will be posted on both channels.**

So you don't have to bother with making sure everyone is on your third channel (which can be painful with large team)

Comment: crude, but yeah that will work